# Non reduced cone point in affine cone of a projective variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral closed subscheme of projective $n$ space over a field. Let $X'$ be its affine cone. Is it possible that $X'$ is nonreduced at the cone point? If so, what is an example?

Edit:

I don't think it can happen.

By taking global sections of the twists of the closed subscheme exact sequence, we have an embedding of the homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$ into $R = \oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, O_X(n))$.

I have convinced myself that this ring $R$ is reduced if $X$ is, and a domain if $X$ is integral.

Pf: If $f,g \in R$ are such that $fg = 0$, by choosing highest degree terms we can assume $f \in O(n)$ and $g \in O(m)$. Then we know that $X = V(fg) = V(f) \cup V(g)$, so without loss assume that $V(f) = X$. But then this means that in each trivialization $O(n)$ to $O_X$, the image of $f$ in $O_X$, $\tilde{f}$, vanishes at all primes. Hence $\tilde{f} = 0$, since the local rings are all reduced. Hence $f = 0$, since trivializations are in particular isomorphisms.

If $f \in R$ is such that $f^n = 0$, again assume $f \in O(n)$. After passing to some cover of trivializations which send $f$ to $\tilde{f}$, we can consider $\tilde{f}^n$ in each local ring, and reducedness implies that $\tilde{f} = 0$. But then this implies that $f = 0$.

Edit:

I thought I was making a mistake, but then realized that at any rate this counter example isn't valid. I'll leave it here.

If $R = k[x,y]/(xy,x^2)$, then $Spec R$ is reduced at the origin, but $Proj R$, for example computed on the chart $D(y)$ (on $D(x)$ it is empty), is just isomorphic to $Spec k[y]$, so it is reduced.

The issue with this counter example: $R$ is not the homogeneous coordinate ring of $Y = Proj(R)$, because $\Gamma_* = \oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(I_Y(n))$ of the ideal sheaf $I_Y$ is larger than $(xy,x^2)$. In particular, $I_Y(1)$ contains $x/y$ on the patch $D(y)$ and $x/x$ on the patch $D(x)$, so we get $x \in \Gamma(I_Y(1))$. (In other words, $(xy,x^2)$ is not saturated.)